# Add data to an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am trying to setup a system where a user can insert there name to be used as there alias for a game. As this will be a multiplayer game I require the array to be able to hold multiple usernames and then display them in order such as player1 then player 2 and then repeat until the game ends.

I have tried the following code to create the `NSMutableArray` this indeed works fine for adding one player but when I then try and add another it replaces the first name I entered. I have been googling this and found that maybe I am creating a new array every time I load this is this the case?

I have declared this at the top of the m file

```
NSMutableArray *players ;
```

Then this is the code I'm using to add the username:

```
- (IBAction)addplayer:(id)sender {


    NSMutableArray *names= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[names addObject: self.username.text];
   NSLog(@"array: %@", names);
}
```

EDIT: I was typing this freehand and got the array name wrong, fixed.

Comment: Where is the `players` array being initialized? Also, what is the `names` array for? From the code you've posted you don't seem to be doing anything with it other than initializing it and logging its description

Comment: do you init players array? what is names? where you use it?

Comment: Sorry was typing this freehand and got the name wrong. The name of the array is names

Comment: when names array after init as soon as (end of block) is deallocated by ARC please define @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
- (IBAction)addplayer:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *names= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [names addObject: self.username.text];
    NSLog(@"array: %@", names);
}
```

This line creates a brand new array:

```
NSMutableArray *names= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Then you add your name to the list like this:

```
[names addObject: self.username.text];
NSLog(@"array: %@", names);
```

Then, the method is done, and `names` is released because it is only defined within the scope of the method.  This means the array, and everything that it contained is no longer in memory.

What you should do, is go to your `ViewController.h` and add this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * names;
```

Then, replace your method with this:

```
- (IBAction)addplayer:(id)sender {
    if (!_names) _names= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // Only creates if necessary

    [_names addObject: self.username.text];
    NSLog(@"array: %@", _names);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You'll want to declare your players array as a property if you're going to use it in multiple places within your class. Add this code between the @interface and @end lines of code in either your .h or .m file (consider whether you need players to be a public array)

   ```
   @property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *players;
   ```

   You will then want to make sure you are initializing the players array somewhere before you use     it. viewDidLoad is a good place for this.

   ```
   self.players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   ```
2. The names array you make goes out of scope once your addPlay method is finished executing. If you want a separate array for usernames, follow step 1. Then in your class you can just call the following code. You don't necessarily need to declare a method to add objects unless you want the array to be logged every time you add and/or want to lazily load the names array.

   ```
   [self.names addObject:self.username.text];
   NSLog(@"array: %@", self.names);
   ```

   Lazy loading means you don't initialize the array until you need it. You wouldn't have to call alloc and init anywhere, but instead would add this code to your addPlayer method.

   ```
   if(!_names) self.names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   ```